# How can I enable EnhancedSessionTransportType on a HyperV VM using powershell?

Tags: powershell, ubuntu, hyper-v

I am trying to use the command:

`Set-VM -VMName "Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS" -EnhancedSessionTransportType HvSocket;`

As per the [following article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2018/02/28/sneak-peek-taking-a-spin-with-enhanced-linux-vms/)

But I just get "Set-VM : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'EnhancedSessionTransportType'"

It seems that this [parameter is not available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/set-vm?view=win10-ps) but all the guides I find still use it!

Comment: It looks like the feature is only available in Windows 10 1803 or higher: https://github.com/Microsoft/linux-vm-tools/issues/27 Maybe newer as it is not listed in the PS docs for `Set-VM`

Comment: Ah - good spot I'm only on version 1709 - which I think is the support version my organistion is running - I'll have to wait for IT in my organisation to push out an update as I'm not able to update manually :(

Comment: You can also get this error if PowerCLI is installed on the host/your workstation. You can qualify the command using `Hyper-V\Set-VM -VMName ...`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning THANK YOU! I was so frustrated since nothing I found on this cmdlet fails to be true and I'm already on 1909. And the reason was VMware!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter doesn't look to be available until Windows 10 1803 or higher per [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/linux-vm-tools/issues/27).